# android MGBox2 library equivalent?

Tags: android, gridview, tableview

Is there an Android equivalent of the [MGBox2](https://github.com/sobri909/MGBox2) library for iOS? Thanks for any pointer!

Answer (score 0):

The library seems to actually be mocking the Android API itself in a lot of ways.  While it's obviously a bit more fancy, there is a clear mimic of Android naming conventions and ease of use with pre-existing Objective-C (or Java in the Android API) data types.

However, given that you appear to want something with a (bad subjective) "better" interface, I'll recommend DroidUX:

http://www.droidux.com/

I haven't used it myself but man, those apps look sexy.  Speaking objectively of course, there's a price tag, which may make it not worth your time.

There are plenty of other custom Views and Animations that the open-source community have created.  I'll update shortly to list a few, but you're probably best off with a google search to try and find something that gets you as close to MGBox2 as possible.